# django tastypie image upload angularjs

Tags: python, django, angularjs, tastypie

I am using angularjs, django, and a tastypie,how to upload image with python/django tastypie. I get `cover: null,` in my api.

```
class InventoryResource(ModelResource):
    cover = fields.FileField(attribute='cover', null=True, blank=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'inventory'
    list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete', 'copy']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post', 'delete', 'copy']
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    authorization = Authorization()
```

models:

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=255,  help_text="Enter inventory name")
    cover        = models.FileField(upload_to = 'static/images/', default = 'static/images/no-image.png')
    created      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   )

def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.manufacturer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading file is not possible with angularjs and django tastypie. You need to do it out of the angularjs and tastypie context.

Create your own Django view specific for uploading (read more at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)), and use angularjs directive to upload, for example: [this directive](https://github.com/tyaslab/angular-tyaslab-upload/).